# Git flow - skipping releases

Tags: git, version-control, git-flow

I've recently started using Git Flow as a source control methodology and was wondering how you'd deal with a scenario where a release is no longer required and for example, the client wants to skip a release, wanting to scrap all recent work and want new features on a new release.

Comment: Do you mean skip **release branches**? And what do you mean "the client wants to skip a release, wanting to scrap all recent work and want new features on a new release"? And what the Git flow you are using now?